# Is There a way to fetch data from mongodb Collection using in Array function. if array id is string

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have Generating the Dynamic Report from mongodb Collections. I fetch Data from one Collection and e.g client and take all client id in Array e.g `["5b7869dff0be71721f53d2e3","5b7869dff0be71721f53d2e4","5b7869dff0be71721f53d2e3"]` When i I fetch data from other collection using **In Array** e.g `{"clientId": { $in: inArray } }` it give me empty result. because in array work if i put `{ "clientId": { $in: [ObjectId('5b785f243cc6c746af635dc8')] } } "ObjectId" word before the id. My Question is how i Put this ObjectId` work in the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use map to map the array to an array of ObjectId

```
inArray = inArray.map( value => ObjectId(value) );
```